# MySQL 5.7.30 "thread_stack" value cannot be updated in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, mysql

After doing a fresh install on Ubuntu 16.04,the "thread_stack" value needs to be updated to 256K(from default 192K) for our application.

We tried to update the value in `my.cnf` with the following parameters.

```
  #
  # * Fine Tuning
  #
  key_buffer        = 16M
  max_allowed_packet    = 16M
  thread_stack              = 262144 //also tried with 256K
  thread_cache_size       = 8

  #Added for activec5 installation
  table_open_cache = 4
  sort_buffer_size = 64K
  read_buffer_size = 256K
  read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
  net_buffer_length = 2K
```

But I received this error,
`mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 27!`

Then I added a preceding ! on each line and the error did not appear but if I do a

```
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%thread_stack%';

   +---------------+--------+
   | Variable_name | Value  |
   +---------------+--------+
   | thread_stack  | 196608 |
   +---------------+--------+
```

The my.cnf file is not read.I also tried to set it through the MYSQL prompt but it says that `ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'thread_stack' is a read only variable`

I also tried to find some other files but did not find any.What am I missing? How can update the value to the actual one?

Comment: @Thomas but how to add it in the file? I mean how to write it exactly so that it works? Do I add the `[group] thread_stack = 256k` or it has to he some other way? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The file `my.cnf` is only a file containing further locations to search for configurations. This is as follows.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

So you shouldn't put any configuration directly into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, but in one of the folders specified.

In your case it would be suitable to create the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/tuning.cnf` whith the lines as follows.

```
[mysqld]
thread_stack = 256k
```

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'thread_stack' is a read only variable

means your
SET GLOBAL thread_stack=nnnnn;
can ONLY be changed in your my.cnf file because it is NOT a Dynamic Global Variable.

Note it is a part of the [mysqld] section.